# Using RemapRange for Reclassify in ArcPy gives ERRORS 000622 and 000628?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, reclassify, error-000628, error-000622

I am trying to reclassify a raster, "Conifer_Focl", which lives in inputData.gdb. The max value for "Conifer_Focl" is 33.217064. I'm looking to reclassify as:[image]

I am following the instructions from [RemapRange](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-transformation-classes.htm), yet I am receiving the following error:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   510, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute
>   (Reclassify). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input
>   into parameter remap.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace = """C:\Users\inputData.gdb"""
inRaster = "Conifer_Focl"
myRemapRange = RemapRange([[0, 1, 100], [1, 2, 85], [2, 3, 75], [3, 4, 65], [4, 7, 40], [7, 10, 20],[10, 33.217064, 0]])

outReclassRR = Reclassify(inRaster, "VALUE", myRemapRange)
outReclassRR.save("reclass.img")
```

Why does this alternate code work (exported from model)? I don't see an output raster name requested.

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("Conifer_Focl", "VALUE", "0 1 100;1 2 85;2 3 75;3 4 65;4 7 40;7 10 20;10 33.217064 0", "Conifer_Modifier_Model3", "DATA")
```

Comment: I think you have your ranges the wrong way around, Can you expand on what your final output values *should* be? Note the newValue should be an integer. It *should* be arcpy.sa.Reclassify but you've imported *everything* from arcpy.sa.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks. Updated with the integer values (decimal values were a previous run).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Does it still give the same error with integer values? It works for me, but as arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[0, 1, 100]... without the raster it's impossible to check any further.

Comment: maybe you also need to set the remapping of NoData values, since they probably exist in your raster? have you already looked at this post? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153771/problems-with-reclassify-and-remaprange-in-arcpy